# Word for office 365

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to create a link, or reference, or something. We produce tech documents for aerospace. I'm tasked with creating a template that has an auto-update feature for certain variables; Doc number, doc name, date, revision number. We want all this info on the front cover, and a link to each one so that when changes are made by users on the cover, that change happens all through the document. If the name is changed on the front cover, that change is shown in the headers and footers. Same with all the other doc properties. I'm trying to avoid having going to tabs and other functional areas to make these changes. My manager wants to make the change on the front cover, and that's all. I am feeling the pressure on this, so if you can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Then you will have to learn vba and write a script to do it.

Comment: You may be able to use a combination of bookmarks and reference fields to accomplish this. Try those terms in an Internet search.

Comment: I find bookmarks can be inadvertently deleted when editing text.  Another approach is to use specific character styles for those few bits of information (eg chDocNo, chDocName, chDate, chRevision).  Then you can use a STYLEREF field in your document where you want to display that info - as there will only be one place where that style is used (the text on cover), it should display the correct info for you.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with StyleRef fields.

On the cover page assign each of the data elements, that you want to replicate throughout the document, a unique Style Name. For example, give the document title a style name of DocTitle, and the Revision Number a style name of RevNumber. Then, at the places throughout the document where you want the Document Title and Revision Number displayed you setup a StyleRef field that references the unique Style Name assigned to that particular piece of information.

A StyleRef field looks like this: **{ STYLEREF. "DocName" }**

Refer to Word's help for more information about the StyleRef field and how to create them. The curly brackets shown in my example, which surround the field controls, are not made with the brackets from your keyboard ... so read carefully the help information on how to insert fields into your documents.